# Google apps script resultset into html

Tags: html, database, google-apps-script, resultset

I have made a connection to an external database and I am fetching data from a particular table. All of it works (tested by putting the results in a log). Now I want to make a GUI in html, but I don't know how to get the data from the .gs file. With that I mean the resultset in `foo()`.

```
 function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
}

function foo() {
  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection("removed, but filled in with my details");
  var stmt = conn.createStatement();
  var rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from orders");
  //while(rs.next()){

    //Logger.log(rs.getString(1));
  //}
  return rs;
  //rs.close();
  //stmt.close();
  //conn.close();
}
```

My html:

```
<html>

<head>
<style>
body{
background-color: #000;
width: 100%;
height: 1000px;
}

#header{
width:100%;
height: 20%;
font-size: 20px;
color: #fff;
}

#content{
color: #fff;
width: 80%;
height: 60%;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="header"><center>Orders</center></div>

<div id="content">
<table>

    <? var data = foo();
     for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) { ?>
    <tr>
      <? for  (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; ++j) { ?>
        <td><?= data[i][j]?></td>
      <? } ?>
    </tr>
  <? } ?>

</table>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the templating approach here, you want the doGet to look like this. Notice the `createHtmlOutputFromFile('file')` vs. `createTemplateFromFile('file').evaluate()`. You can find more info on this here - https://developers.google.com/apps-script/html_service#TemplatedHTML

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index').evaluate()
}
```